# lapply on dataframe list using different column index

Tags: r, lapply, r-caret

I'm try to do a feature selection on a dataframe list using the caret package. I have different dataframes but the last 6 columns are the same. When I am trying to apply the model on a single df it works fine

```
# For a single dataframe
mx.chem # the name of my single dataframe
#define the control   
mx.control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method = "cv", number = 10) 
# run the rfe     
mx.results <- rfe(mx.chem[,1:22], mx.chem[,23], sizes = c(1:22), rfeControl = mx.control)
print(mex.results)
```

but My problem is when I try to use lapply on a list of df. The code I have until now is

```
 require(mlbench)
 require(caret)
 mylist # is a df list containing 3 df 
  for (i in 1:3) {
  my.control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method = "cv", number = 10)  # define the control
  longdata <- length(i)-6
  idxindustry <- longdata +1
  my.results <- lapply(mylist, function(x) rfe ( x[,1:longdata], x[,idxindustry], data = x, sizes =c(1:longdata), rfeControl = my.control))
  }
```

I'm not sure if I'm using column index properly. Does anyone have an idea how to fix to make my code work. Thanks

Comment: There does not appear to be a `data` argument for [rfe](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/rfe). [Link here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/rfe). It is currently being passed to the model fitting. Is that intended?

Comment: I've just edit my question. My problem is when i want to use lapply. I do not know how to specify a column on the a dataframe contained on a list

Comment: `longdata <- length(i)-6` is not doing what you think. `i` takes on three values `1 2 3`. So you want `longdata` to be `length(1)-6` and so on? The length of a single number is always `1`. So `longdata` is `-5` each time. Do you see why?

Comment: Please explain the `for` loop that is looping through `1 2 3`

Comment: I'm using a `for`loop that is looping through 3 df that are on `mylist`. Reading your previous comment it makes me think that my problem is on my loop. should I use `seq_len` to get the total number of columns and then substract the last 6?

Comment: Use a for loop or `lapply`, not both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible ways:

```
#Using lapply
mx.control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method = "cv", number = 10) 
rfe.lst <- lapply(mylist, 
           function(x) {
               longdata <- ncol(x)-6
               rfe ( x[,1:longdata], x[,longdata + 1], 
                         sizes =c(1:longdata), 
                         rfeControl = mx.control)
               })

#For loop
mx.control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method = "cv", number = 10) 
rfe.lst <- vector("list", 3)
for(i in 1:3) {
  longdata <- ncol(mylist[[i]])-6
  rfe.lst[[i]] <- rfe(mylist[[i]][,1:longdata], x[,longdata + 1],
      sizes=c(1:longdata),
      rfeControl=mx.control)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't do what you think. `length(i)` will always be 1, because i is your loop index and takes the values 1 to 3. You mean to do:

```
length(mylist[[i]])
```

Note the double brackets. That's how you select the element from the list, in this case the data frame. If you use single brackets, you get back a list with the elements you want.

But that's still not what you aim to achieve. If you would change that line in your code, you have 2 loops:

- an outer loop that creates `longdata` and `idxindustry` based on a single data frame each time.
- an inner `lapply` loop that uses the values for `longdata` and `idxindustry` on all three dataframes.

Remember that `lapply` takes each element in the list and passes it as the first argument to the function you specify. So you can do this in a single `lapply` like this:

```
my.control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method = "cv", number = 10)  

my.results <- lapply(mylist, function(x){
# x becomes one of the data frames in the list mylist here, so you can
# treat it like a data frame in the code below
  longdata <- length(x) - 6
  idxindustry <- longdata +1
  rfe( x[,1:longdata], x[,idxindustry], data = x, 
      sizes =c(1:longdata), rfeControl = my.control)
})
```

And then you run `rfe` with `longdata` and `idxindustry` based on the data frame at hand. Note I put the call to `rfeControl` outside the `lapply` loop for performance.